Upgrading Gradle from 8.0.0 to Gradle 8.3.2 gives error on generate build . type converter not identified related
    @TypeConverters(CommonConverter::class)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {}

here I used CommonConverter for Type converted.
 package com.uch.common.db;

import android.text.TextUtils;

import androidx.room.TypeConverter;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.uch.common.utils.DateHandlingUtil;
import com.uch.common.model.AiSpecialtyReport;
import com.uch.common.model.Result;
import com.uch.common.utils.Logger;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CommonConverter {
    private final static DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(
            DateHandlingUtil.AppDateFormat.SERVER_DATE_TIME_FORMAT.getValue(), Locale.ENGLISH);
    private final static String TAG = CommonConverter.class.getSimpleName();

   /* @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }*/

    @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(String value) {
        if (value != null) {
            try {
                df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                return df.parse(value);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Logger.error(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromDate(Date value) {
        if (value != null) {
            try {
                df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                return df.format(value);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.error(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Object fromObjectString(String value) {
        Type objType;
        try {
            objType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType();
            return new Gson().fromJson(value, objType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
            objType = new TypeToken<String>() {
            }.getType();
        }
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, objType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromObject(Object value) {
        return new Gson().toJson(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<String> toArrayListString(String value) {
        Type objType;
        try {
            objType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType();
            return new Gson().fromJson(value, objType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayListString(ArrayList<String> value) {
        return new Gson().toJson(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static ArrayList<Result> toArrayListResult(String value) {
        Type objType;
        try {
            objType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Result>>() {
            }.getType();
            return new Gson().fromJson(value, objType);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayListResult(ArrayList<Result> value) {
        return new Gson().toJson(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromJsonArray(JsonArray value) {
        try {
            return value.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static JsonArray toJsonArray(String value) {
        try {
            return JsonParser.parseString(value).getAsJsonArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromCategory(AiSpecialtyReport.Category value) {
        try {
            return value.name();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static AiSpecialtyReport.Category toCategory(String value) {
        try {
            return AiSpecialtyReport.Category.valueOf(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromDevice(AiSpecialtyReport.Device value) {
        try {
            return value.name();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static AiSpecialtyReport.Device toDevice(String value) {
        try {
            return AiSpecialtyReport.Device.valueOf(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromVerificationStatus(AiSpecialtyReport.VerificationStatus value) {
        try {
            return value.name();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static AiSpecialtyReport.VerificationStatus toVerificationStatus(String value) {
        try {
            return AiSpecialtyReport.VerificationStatus.valueOf(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromProcessStatus(AiSpecialtyReport.ProcessStatus value) {
        try {
            return value.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return "";
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static AiSpecialtyReport.ProcessStatus toProcessStatus(String value) {
        try {
            return AiSpecialtyReport.ProcessStatus.valueOf(value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public String fromStringMap(HashMap<String, String> value) {
        try {
            final Map<String, String> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(value);
            return TextUtils.join(",", sortedMap.keySet())
                    .concat("<divider>")
                    .concat(TextUtils.join(",", sortedMap.values()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public HashMap<String, String> toStringMap(String value) {
        try {
            final String[] keysValsSep = value.split("<divider>");
            final String[] keys = keysValsSep[0].split(",");
            final Iterator<String> valuesIterator = Arrays.asList(keysValsSep[1].split(",")).iterator();
            final HashMap<String, String> strMap = new HashMap<>();

            for (String key : keys) {
                strMap.put(key, valuesIterator.next());
            }
            return strMap;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.warn(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}

Above code I used CommonConverter.Earlier it's working fine but now I upgrade gradle system 8.3.4 after shows error: Cannot figure out how to save this field into database. You can consider adding a type converter for it.
private error.NonExistentClass ecgData;
@ColumnInfo(name = DBConstants.COL_ECG_DATA)
    @SerializedName(DBConstants.COL_ECG_DATA)
    var ecgData: ArrayList<String>? = null

how solve this error anyone help me? Note: Gradle system 8.0.0 no error occurred and also Dao_impl file generate successfully. now Dao_impl file is also not generated. After the Gradle system update this error comes
